# Find the before the last file was created in the folder or directory in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I faced some issue while i list all the files in my directory , i would like to print or fetch just the file which is before the last file was modified

```
server:cd user/local
server/user/local/: ls -ltrh 

-rw-r--r--  1 Pepe  staff     0B Nov  7 13:40 1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Pepe  staff     0B Nov  7 13:40 2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Pepe  staff     0B Nov  7 13:40 3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Pepe  staff     0B Nov  7 13:58 5.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Pepe  staff     9B Nov  7 14:25 6.txt
```

I hope i can have the result **`5.txt`**

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex-looking pipeline, but each piece is pretty straightforward:

```bash
stat -c '%Y:%n' * | sort -t: -n | cut -d: -f2- | tail -2 | head -1
```

check your `stat` man page to see if your version has the `-c` option.

Comment: Thats Great , actually it is also working for me like :

`ls -ltrh | tail -2 | head -1`

Comment: `ls` is intended for humans to read. [why you should not use it for parsing data](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- in fact my answer is still broken for filenames containing newlines.

Comment: Your script does not check for files only (it will list the second latest modified entry in current directory).